# /usr/local/bin/npm no such file or directory ubuntu

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed nodejs

*nodejs --version
v10.1.0*

And node

*node --version
v9.2.0*

But npm is giving error

*npm -version
bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory*

I have tried many solutions but none of them are working. I think either the package got broken or some other problems are there. I am not able to find the correct solution for this. Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: What does it say in the terminal when you type `which node` or `which npm`?

Comment: For which npm, it's giving the path **/usr/bin/npm**
and for which node, it's giving the path **/usr/local/bin/node**

Comment: What about `npm --version`

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231608/npm-version-bash-usr-bin-npm-no-such-file-or-directory#answer-72396849