# npm version -bash: /usr/bin/npm: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, bash, path

I'm aware that the error is because node.js and npm weren't installed in /usr/bin

its in /file/file/nodejs/bin

but editing the .bash_profile and adding :/file/file/nodejs/bin to $PATH is still returning the same error.

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/file/file/nodejs/bin

export PATH

any help would be greatly appreciated, I can't move where it was installed because it's on a VM that I don't have full access to, but I can edit the bash_profile

Comment: does someting have `/usr/bin` hard coded in it?  Also, is `export PATH` really on the same line as the PATH setting or is it just not formatted?

Comment: that was just bad pasting, export path is on it's own line sorry. Also unless it's hard coded in npm I don't see anything in the .bash_profile that would do it

Comment: Did you logout and back in again after editing `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @JRFerguson So I'm officailly jumping off a bridge. That's all it was.... Thank you so much, I've been banging my head for almost 2 hours and I just forgot to reload the session

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu:

```
apt install nodejs
```

if you `run nvm which`, will see something similar `/usr/bin/node`

for install node version 16 run below commands:

```
nvm install 16
nvm use 16
node --version
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node
```

and so for install node version 10 run below commands:

```
nvm install 10
nvm use 10
node --version
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.x.y/bin/node
```